# How to detect connection is down in gRPC?

Tags: c++, grpc

How to detect from a client side of C++ gRPC blocking client that connection is no longer available and I should perform reconnection attempt? And how to reconnect correctly?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/3954

Comment: Thank you, but how to reconnect? Do i need to create a new instance of Channel & Stub?

Comment: Channels automatically reconnect using exponential backoff.

Comment: What is the default parameters of backoff policy? I connected to RPC, then kill the server, and the next call is ALWAYS return error. After that next calls are ok, looks like reconnection have been succesfully done.  Have tried channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 1000) with no result; I expected that when server is restarted, after 1s connection established automatically. Am I right?

Comment: Mistake in me last comment: I kill the server, that start it again.

Comment: @odiszapc Can you please tell how you solved this? I am trying with `set_deadline()` but it is not able detect dropped connection.

Comment: @PrashantShubham Is there a way to know instantly that the server is unreachable for the client? I ant to validate a scenario where authentication is successful and then the connection is lost.

Comment: @RC0993 try this check:
`if ((grpcClient->status).error_code() == grpc::StatusCode::OK) {
      INFO("GRPC connection exists");
      return 0;
   }`
You can have a while loop to keep checking the status_code if it is other than OK.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you are referring to here. I am working with [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe.cc) approach as of now, where are you suggesting the check to be applied? I came across some terms like "keepalive" "set_deadline" do you have some info on that?